# IIS rewriting ala SO

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

Lets say that I have a site called

> http://sub.example.com/

I want to rewrite requests so that when a user types in:

> http://sub.example.com/id/company-name

It should internally be rewritten to:

> http://sub.example.com/public.aspx

(I guess this is similar to the way SO question links are handled, where all questions have a unique id and a not unique title, and only the id is used to generate the page. This way an old link to a question will still work even after the title of the question has been changed)

I try to do this: 
In `Application_BeginRequest` in `global.aspx` I first recognizing that the requested page is a “public” page. Then I make a

> HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/public/default.aspx",
>   False)

In `~/public/default.aspx` I then fetch the id to dynamically generate a company specific page (company logo and name for instance).
This is working well on my local development environment but at the server it seems that Application_BeginRequest is not triggered. I guess this is because the requested folder does not exist?

How do I solve this problem, or are there better ways to implement this behavior?

Comment: The question IDs are part of the REST routes. The titles are for SEO. You're probably doing neither REST nor heavy SEO. I would instead ignore the way SO does it. But yes, you want a default redirect on pages not existing.

Answer (score 1):

On IIS6 I used [URL Rewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/) (Open Source, free). On IIS 7 (or 7.5) I successfully used the [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) module from Microsoft.